# how to parse "Respond to Power App or Flow" body

Tags: power-automate

I have flow that is designed to retrieve data from a RESTful JSON API. to do this, the flow must first call an oauth endpoint to obtain an access token which must be included as a header for any data requests. I want to keep the oauth flow separate from the data flow so it can be used by other data flows also.
my GET data flows look similar to this.
[image: data_request_flow]

the authentication flow is as per below and completes successfully.
[image: authentication_flow]

the payload being returned to the primary flow is as follows...

```
{
  "straccesstoken": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

my 'Parse auth response' step is essentially trying to identify the `straccesstoken` value. the problem that I'm having is that when the primary flow tries to parse the response, the following error is returned.

> InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson'
> must be valid JSON. The provided value cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected
> character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0,
> position 0.'.

the 'Call authentication flow' response looks correct and has the header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` but it still can't parse the content.

can anyone help me understand why the auth response isn't being interpreted as JSON and offer help on how to fix my flow? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your authentication flow is using the wrong operation to return the access token.  You need to use the `Response` operation, not the one associated to PowerApps ...

[image: Flow]